# rc.local only runs manually, not on boot

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi 2 to automatically email its IP address when it boots. I included my entire /etc/rc.local file below for reference. When I manually run the file, I get an email with the Pi's IP address, as expected. It has never worked automatically when booting. Why doesn't email script run on boot as expected and how do I fix it? I tried removing the ampersand (&) and its presence did not make a difference.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
  python /home/pi/code/startup_mailer.py &
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: can you try it with the full path to python (/usr/bin/python)? you should also try using the full path for the hostname and printf commands.

Comment: During boot rc.local run as root. In order to check if it could run you should try 'sudo su - -c /etc/rc.local'. Is there anything on the boot console ?

Comment: Here's an idea for debugging/logging from `rc.local`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189415/25985

Answer (score 3):

`rc.local`, whether you should or shouldn't be using it, will only run if:

1. It is marked as executable (+x)
2. You're on a system that hasn't deprecated `rc.local` (ie: `systemctl`)

Since you're dealing with IP addresses and Mail, why not load your script via `/etc/network/interfaces` with the following:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up /path/to/your/script.py
```

#### Notes

- [`rc.local` doesn't log anywhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/434276/13247) or have any output.

Comment: How can the system determine whether or not `rc.local` will produce output before running it?

Comment: `bash /etc/rc.local` ?  Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I am asking about point #2 of your answer "(rc.local will only run if) There is no OUTPUT". How is that possible? Could you provide a reference supporting this claim? It sounds like a corollary to [the "Halting Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: `cron` scripts can't have output. `rc.local` just doesn't provide output normally.  I'll update the ticket, thanks for the callout.

Comment: Ah, OK that makes a lot more sense. The script can include commands that would generate output, but it will not go anywhere visible.

Answer (score 0):

In the python program, add the location of where it should start. Add it as a command like this  `import os
os.system("cd /path/to/script")` .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ANY file referenced in your python code has an absolute path.
Example:

```
f = open('/path/to/file.txt')
```

instead of:

```
f = open('file.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the same problem like you do.
Then I insert this sentenses in the beginning of my script:

```
log_file = open ( '/my_path/mylogfile' )
log_file.write( 'Anything.' )
log_file.close()
```

After restart, there is something in mylogfile.
In fact, my script has been executed, but exited by some exeption.

So I insert this line in the rc.local right before my script:

```
sleep 15
```

It worked!